# Why is my private user to user chat showing in other user's chat profile?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a private user to user chat, I'm facing an issue where when a user send messages with another user, this same chat appear on the chat of other users.

Let's say user A contacted user B, user C can not see the messages sent between users A & B, but users A & B can see their discussion on user C's chat profile who have nothing to do with them.

**Question :** How can I make it so it only shows the chat when it has to do with the sender and the recipient ?

The chat profile is shown at the url page like so : `/c/<recipient username>/`

As you can see the image below, everything is correct because the url username match the sender or recipient username.

[image]

As you can see on this other image, the url username has nothing to do with the send or recipient username.

[image]

Here is my **template file** :

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.client == request.user %}
         <li style="text-align:left; background:yellow;">
             <p>from {{ user.client }} to <strong>{{ user.worker }} </strong> | {{ user.sent_at }}</p>                         
             <p>{{ user.comment }}</p>
         </li>
    {% else %}
         <li style="text-align:right; background:#eaeaea;">
             <p>from {{ user.client }} to <strong>{{ user.worker }}</strong> | {{ user.sent_at }}</p>
             <p>{{ user.comment }}</p>
         </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def comment(request, username):
    username = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user = userComment.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(recipient=request.user)).order_by('sent_at')

    context = {'users': user, 'url_username': username}
    return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class userComment(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="recipient")
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

I don't know wether it has to do with the views or the template, any suggestion ?

Comment: you haven't shown the view where the query is performed

Comment: @e4c5 How should I do it ?

Comment: You are using `request.user` to query the comments and the username that you passed in URL has no connection with the query. Are you logged in with same account while testing?

Comment: @maverick yes I'm logged as the same account, but that's the problem I shouldn't see the chat between me and "huriddin52" on "huriddin1" chat's profile

Comment: So you want those comments that are either posted by logged in user and recieved by recipient in the URL or sent by recipient in the URL and recieved by logged in user? Am i correct?

Comment: If you're logged with the same account you will obviously see your own chats - as maverick mentions you are filtering on `request.user` (you do understand that `request.user` is the logged in user do you?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to query

```
users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(Q(sender=request.user) & Q(recipient=username)) | Q(Q(sender=username) & Q(recipient=request.user))).order_by('sent_at')
```

Comment: Words can't express how I am thankfull, I've been on it for days.